# C# vs ASP in developing a web application

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, asp.net-mvc

I have a coursework which requires me to do the following :

1. Make a website which can retrieve data from application db
2. Create three data repositories (two as application db and one as data warehouse)
3. Ensure that the two application db can sync their data with the data warehouse

I have intermediate knowledge in Java programming but I am thinking that I would like to try developing this in another language. Here is what I was planning to use (and also my confusion)

I am planning to use IIS to host the databases on multiple computers and I decided to use ASP.NET as my programming language for website and C# as its backend but I am confused about the relationship between ASP/ASP.NET and C#. It seems to me that having ASP/ASP.NET/ASP.NET-MVC is sufficient to build the whole thing without needing C#. Can someone please explain the differences to me? I am still at lost after reading about them the whole morning.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well,

The difference are lot. Please learn this below links.

- [ASP is a old version](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Common_Intermediate_Language)
- [ASP.NET is advanced version than ASP](http://www.appsntech.com/2012/02/what-is-difference-between-asp-and.html)
- [ASP.NET MVC is more advanced version than ASP.NET](http://www.dotnet-tricks.com/Tutorial/mvc/017O031112-Difference-between-Asp.Net-WebForm-and-Asp.Net-MVC.html)

You can click the above link for a difference.

also see this below discussion for

[Relationship between C#, .NET, ASP, ASP.NET etc](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/44810/relationship-between-c-net-asp-asp-net-etc)

the answer have:

I understand your confusion, believe me I have the same perspective when it comes to the Java world! Anyway I'll attempt to break your questions down and tackle them one by one... as well as add some other points in that will hopefully help clarify what's going on:

1. C# and C#.NET are the same thing... C#
2. .NET is, as you say, a library of code that .NET languages can talk to.
3. .NET languages come in different flavours such as: C#.NET, VB.NET, Managed C++, F#.
4. .NET languages compile to CIL ([Common Intermediate Language](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Common_Intermediate_Language)) which means they all start "talking" the same language and can therefore interoperate.
5. ASP.NET is the portion of the .NET library used for making web sites. There are other subsections of ASP.NET like WebForms (the old way of making web pages) or the rapidly maturing MVC library that are worth looking at too.
6. Forms (old tech) or the new WPF (Windows Presentation Foundation) are the technologies you'd typically use in .NET to create what you know as traditional desktop applications.

One final thing I'd like to finish on is the difference between library and framework. In recent years these two terms have been used as those synonymous, however that is not the case. The easiest way I can think to differentiate the two is:

- A library contains many pieces of functionality that you may pick and choose from i.e. using one piece of technology doesn't mean you're locked into the rest. This means freedom, however you will have more work cut out for you.
- A framework however very much sets out how you will be working be providing a workflow that for better or worse is hard to change. This means rapid development/prototyping, but if significant changes are made in the future it may be impossible (or very time consuming) to implement them.

The project you're working on will depend on which choice you make.